# How can I access argc and argv in c++ from a library function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

I'm writing a library which is to be dynamically loaded in C++.

I'd like to read argc and argv (for debugging reasons) from within my code, however I do not have access to the main function. Is there any way to retrieve the command line (both Windows and Linux solution would be nice).

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 12):

There is the GetCommandLine() function in the Win32 API.  On other platforms, you would have to save argc/argv somewhere (external variable?).

Answer (score 12):

On Linux the pseudo-file /proc/self/cmdline holds the command line for the process.  Each argument is terminated with a 0 byte, and the final argument is followed by an additional 0 byte.

Answer (score 6):

On windows you can access argc/argv via __argc and __argv.
__wargv if you want the wide character version.

Comment: This is a truly terrible idea! Any symbol whose name begins with two underscores is reserved for internal use by the compiler implementation. You should ___never___ refer to these in user code. This is a classical example of self-inflicted undefined behaviour -- any (potentially undesirable) outcome is possible.

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest that this sounds like a weird situation. Are you writing a plugin or something? Perhaps you should not access argv/argc?

Comment: I agree.  If a library needs access to argv and argc, then the library probably could use a redesign.

Comment: GTK+ needs (or accepts, not sure) argc&argv for parsing, say, the --display parameter. It could be useful in this case, too; think "--debug".

Comment: argv and argc are passed to GTK+ which is perfectly sensible.  What I was referring to - and what DanJ is asking for - was a way for a library to access argv and argc.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows you can use [GetCommandLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156(VS.85).aspx) to get a pointer to the command line and then use [CommandLineToArgvW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(VS.85).aspx) to convert that pointer to argv[] format. There is only a wide (Unicode) version available, though.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, I use this type of thing to get the arguments:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cwchar>
#include <cstdio>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

vector<wstring> getArgs() {
    int argc;
    wchar_t** argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    vector<wstring> args;
    if (argv) {
        args.assign(argv, argv + argc);
        LocalFree(argv);
    }
    return args;
}

int main() {
    const vector<wstring> argv = getArgs();
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".OCP");
    for (vector<wstring>::const_iterator i = argv.begin(); i != argv.end(); ++i) {
        wprintf(L"%s\n", i->c_str());
    }
}
```

Edit: A getArgs function like that is also useful for mingw as mingw doesn't support a wmain().

Answer (score 1):

This should work under linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void findargs(int *argc, char ***argv) {
    size_t i;
    char **p = &__environ[-2];
    for (i = 1; i != *(size_t*)(p-1); i++) {
        p--;
    }
    *argc = (int)i;
    *argv = p;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("got argc=%d, argv=%p\n", argc, argv);
    findargs(&argc, &argv);
    printf("found argc=%d, argv=%p\n", argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: fails if setenv() has been called.*

Answer (score 0):

Use getpid() and ps command.

int pid;

int fd;

char cmd[80];

pid = getpid();

sprintf(cmd, "ps %d", pid);

fd = popen(cmd, "r");

.... lines should be like

.... 1358 ./a.out abc def

Answer (score 0):

Have you given any thought to using environment variables instead of the command line? Might be easier on the user depending on what kinds of applications the library will be used in, and you can use the standard getenv() function.

I think, in any case, if your library is going to use argc and argv, the program should be the one to pass them.